# Графы, подсчёт изолированных вершин с помощью матрицы смежности, код выдаёт неверный ответ

Tags: python, графы

решала следующую задачу:

```
На острове расположены несколько государств, изолированных 
друг от друга. У программиста Васи есть данные обо всех дорогах 
острова, заданные в виде весовой матрицы соответствующего графа, 
узлы которого – города, а веса рёбер – расстояния между ними. 
Напишите программу, которая определяет, сколько государств, 
состоящих из единственного города, находится на острове.

Входные данные
В первой строке вводится количество городов на карте N ( 1 ≤ N ≤ 1000 ).
 В следующих N строках записано по N чисел, разделённых пробелами – 
элементы весовой матрицы графа, который описывает схему дорог.

Выходные данные
Программа должна вывести номера всех государств, состоящих из одного 
города, в порядке возрастания. Нумерация начинается с единицы. Если 
таких городов нет, нужно вывести число 0.

Примеры
входные данные
5
0 1 2 0 0
1 0 3 0 0
2 3 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
выходные данные
4 5
```

Написала по ней код:

```
n=int(input()) 
a=[list(map(int, input().split())) for i in range(n)]
ans1=[]
for i in range(n):
    if len(set(a[i]))==1:
        ans1.append(i+1)
ans2=[] 
for i in range(n):
    q=0 
    for j in range(n):
        q+=a[j][i] 
    if q==0:
        ans2.append(i+1)
if len(ans1)==0 or len(ans2)==0:
    print(0) 
else:
    for i in ans1:
        if i in ans2:
            print(i, end=" ")
```

Но на трёх тестах проверяющей системы код выдаёт неверный ответ, помогите пожалуйста!!!
Ссылка на задачу:
https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=83389&chapterid=479#1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Система не принимает ответ так как вы, я и другие участники на этом сайте предположили что матрица графа симметричная. Это естественное предположение для термина "граф" без уточнений. Тем не менее составители задачи считают по другому.

Этот код проходит все тесты:

```
n = int(input())
a = [[int(w) for w in input().split()] for _ in range(n)]

answer = [
    i + 1
    for i in range(n)
    if all(a[i][j] == 0 and a[j][i] == 0 for j in range(n) if j != i)
]

if answer:
    print(*answer)
else:
    print(0)
```

Ещё один вариант. Сложность по памяти уменьшена до *O(N)*:

```
n = int(input())

isolated = [True] * n

for i in range(n):
    for j, w in enumerate(map(int, input().split())):
        if w != 0 and i != j:
            isolated[i] = False
            isolated[j] = False

answer = [i + 1 for i in range(n) if isolated[i]]
if answer:
    print(*answer)
else:
    print(0)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но поясните пожалуйста, какую роль выполняет all, просто я с ним ещё не встречалась

Comment: `all` проверяет что все выражения внутри скобок истинны. В данном конкретном случае проверяется что крест с центром *i, i* целиком нулевой.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, код работает)

Comment: `a[i][j] == 0 and a[j][i] == 0`  по-хорошему надо для `i != j` проверять, потому что дорога из города в него же не соединяет его ни с кем.

Comment: @Qwertiy, поправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##XYyxDoMwDER3vuLE5KgIOaBK/Z0MpTWijhXSga9PQ9qpi@9J98525GfU@WapFEuimXr04xpF6RWM9pwGkFw8lpggEEUK@rjTaYraO5NzDrJAY0bQo61qOeDXjrtt0qxTrE/YlXLtGB4TGNz5eudG0zcrMfifPg)

```
print(" ".join(map(str, (i+1 for i in range(int(input())) if not any(map(int, input().split()))))) or 0)
```

Если в графе разрешены петли, то немного хитрее: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoMwEETvfsXUU0JFEqXQix8TaGxX6ibECPr1aZLSSy@7D@bN@DO@HI93H1LygTiKFm2/OGKxGi@2GDoIumrMLoBAjGD4aUUxif0ehZQSNINdhOGzBofM@Mj6ZcJSm0t3lK7lfbXBRPvr9pt/U90oM1lUMqVbo6AxQEE1Ot@x0vD9mRTUH@kP)

```
print(" ".join(map(str, (i+1 for i in range(int(input())) if not any(int(x) and i != j for j,x in enumerate(input().split()))))) or 0)
```

Comment: Ответ исправлен. Сначала 0 забыл.

Comment: Читайте вопрос внимательно. Ответы, которые перечисляют нулевые строки не принимаются.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, уже 4 раза перечитал и не вижу такого в нём.

Comment: Я подавал решения  в проверяющую систему.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ok, подумал, дополнил.

Comment: Я уже разобрался. На входе несимметричные матрицы. Надо проверять не только строку но и столбец.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хм.. по тексту совершенно не догадаться, что граф ориентированный...

Comment: Ещё и веса рёбер названы расстояними. А расстояния симметричны. Но что, то есть. Я убил сутки на эту задачу. 20 подач.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну в городах односторонние дороги бывают. Но всё равно формулировка у них так себе.