# Задача о подсчете дорог, код выдаёт неверный ответ

Tags: python, графы

Всем привет, решала следующую задачу:

> ограничение по времени 1 секунда ограничение по памяти 256 мегабайт
>
> В Ваканде есть N городов, некоторые из которых соединены дорогами.
> Король решил провести инвентаризацию дорог, но оказалось, что он не
> силен в математике, поэтому он просит вас посчитать количество дорог.
> Требуется написать программу, помогающую Королю сосчитать количество
> дорог в Ваканде.
>
> Входные данные В первой строке записано число N, 0≤N≤100 .
>
> В следующих N строках записано по N чисел, каждое из которых является
> единичкой или ноликом. Причем, если в позиции (i, j) квадратной
> матрицы  стоит единичка, то i-ый и j-ый города соединены дорогами, а
> если нолик,  то не соединены. Гарантируется, что все дороги соединяют
> различные города.
>
> Выходные данные Необходимо вывести число, определяющее количество
> дорог в Ваканде.

```
Пример
входные данные
5
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
выходные данные
3
```

Написала по ней код, но он на некоторых тестах выдает неверный ответ, не понимаю почему.

```
n=int(input())
cnt=0
for i in range(n):
    a=list(map(int, input().split()))
    cnt+=sum(a)
print(cnt//2)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку!!!

Comment: А помните "...вы, я и другие участники на этом сайте предположили что матрица графа симметричная."?

Comment: А что неправильно, собственно? Всё верно.

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка, если матрица симметричная, то всё верно, а если нет?

Answer (score 0):

По аналогии с другой [задачей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1535087) предположу что составители подают на вход ориентированные графы с несимметричной матрицей. Тогда нужно учитывать все дороги, включая одностороние. Двустороняя дорога идёт как единица за оба направления:

```
roads = set()
for i in range(int(input())):
    for j, v in enumerate(input().split()):
        if v == '1':
            roads.add(tuple(sorted((i, j))))
print(len(roads))
```